# Android can't see application icon after installation

Tags: android, apk

I developed an application with Android studio and there is a very strange behavior:
After the installation I cant see the application (not the icon nor the name) in all apps list, but I can see that in recent apps and in manage apps.
I sent the APK to myself in email and after the installation the open option was disabled.
I checked the `ic_launcher` icons and they are fine.

What can cause that? Any ideas?

EDIT:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="my.package.name"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="9"
        android:targetSdkVersion="18" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".SplashActivity"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
                <data android:scheme="http" android:host="my.package.name.host" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity"
                  android:configChanges="orientation"/>

        <activity android:name=".LoginActivity"
                  android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"
                  android:configChanges="orientation"/>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: you need to mention that in manifest too. share your manifest.xml file

Comment: the manifest also good

Comment: Does your manifest include the  <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />?

Comment: I don't think Android Studio built a correct APK for you ... can you see your logcat? Maybe you will understand what's going on.

Comment: Is your icon available in a folder like `/drawable` or only in `/drawable-hdpi` or something? Perhaps it doesn't exist in a location that works for their device?

Comment: The icon is OK, it worked before. I just can't understand the change I did.

Comment: It happened once for me when I added something in my <intent-filter> , just remove some lines and try if it works

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For me having the following lines in the **intent-filter** were enough to make the ICON appear in the launcher with the other apps

```
     <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
     </intent-filter>
```

When you open the apk, that was sent by email or transfer to your phone you will see the **INSTALL** option and after succesfully installed the **OPEN** option is there.

Answer (score 2):

Put tags at two intent-filters like here

```
     <activity android:name=".MainActivity"
              android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
        </intent-filter>

        <intent-filter>

            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
            <data android:scheme="http" android:host="qr_3d.com"/>
            <data android:scheme="https" android:host="qr_3d.com"/>
            <data android:scheme="app" android:host="qr_3d.com"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the filter is as

should be MAIN and not activity_main, etc.

also remove min / max SDK setting line...

This worked for me